# The convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1\over \ln(n!)}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Check the convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} {1\over \ln(n!)}$.

I tried D'Alembert's test... Cauchy's test seems too intricate... I can't seem to understand what I should do here...

Comment: Whatdo you know about$n!$? Do you know Stirling's approximation?

Comment: Never heard of it but I shall look at my teacher's note.. Maybe he taught it and I never notices..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\sum \frac{1}{\log(n!)}$ diverges it suffices to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ diverges as the other answers have shown.

Here is an elementary proof that $\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges (since OP said he did not know integrals). We start with a little lemma:

> If $a_n\geq 0$ is a sequence and $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ then 
>   $$\log\left(\frac{s_N}{s_{1}}\right) \leq \sum_{n=2}^N\frac{a_n}{s_{n-1}}$$

Proof: We have

$$\log\left(\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}}\right) = \log\left(1 + \frac{a_n}{s_{n-1}}\right) \leq \frac{a_n}{s_{n-1}}$$

since $\log(1+x)\leq x$ for all $x\geq 0$. By summing over $n=2,3,\ldots,N$ we get

$$\log\left(\frac{s_N}{s_{1}}\right) \leq \sum_{n=2}^N\frac{a_n}{s_{n-1}}$$

We first apply the lemma above to $a_n=1$ to obtain

$$\log\left(N\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n}$$

We then proceed to apply the lemma to $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$ to find

$$\log\left(\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{i}\right) \leq \sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{i}} \leq \sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n\log n}$$

where we have used the inequality derived above in the last step. Finally since the harmonic series diverges so does the logarithm and it follows that $\sum \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges.

$\mathbf{Remark:}$ By continuing to apply the lemma above to $a_n = \frac{1}{n\log n}$ (and so on), the method above can be used to show that $\sum \frac{1}{n\log(n)\log(\log(n))\ldots \log^{(k)}(n)}$ diverges for any $k$. However, this result follows much more simply from the integral test.

Comment: This is good to see. (If only to remind us how useful the integral test can be ;-) )

Comment: @SimonS I agree, the integral test is well worth learning:) However the lemma above can be very useful for other stuff like this cute little problem for example: "Is there a function $\phi(n)$ s.t. $\sum a_n$ converges iff $\lim_{n\to \infty} \phi(n) a_n = 0$?" The lemma with $a_n = 1/\phi(n)$ gives a contradiction (a favoritte problem of mine, just had to mention it:)

Comment: But 8ln8 is bigger the 8 :(

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

$$\ln n! = \ln n + \ln (n-1) + \cdots + \ln 2 + \ln 1 \le n\ln n$$
so
$$\frac{1}{\ln n!} \ge \frac{1}{n\ln n}$$
Does
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\ln n}$$
converge?

**Hint 2:**

If you can't use the integral test, determining the convergence/divergence of $\sum\frac{1}{n\ln n}$ is somewhat difficult.  Here's a hint on how you can do it:

$$\sum_{n=2}^{2^{k+1}-1}a_n = \sum_{n=1}^{k}\sum_{m=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1}a_m$$

$$\sum_{m=2^n}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{1}{m\ln m} > \left(2^{n+1}-1 - 2^n + 1\right) \left(\frac{1}{(2^{n+1})\ln2^{n+1}}\right) = \frac{1}{2\ln2}\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Notice that this is similar to how we usually prove that the [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#Comparison_test) diverges.

Comment: Instead of breaking down the $\ln$ like that, you can just use the fact that $n! \leq n^n$ to get the same result, which is a more obvious step IMO.

Comment: @Soke  I see breaking the logarithm of the 'product' $n!$ into the sum of logarithms as the most natural first step, but to each their own.  Your method definitely works just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that for all $N > 2$,

$$\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{\ln n!} > \sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n \cdot \ln n}$$

Now what do you know about the convergence of that second series?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $$\ln(n^n) \geq \ln(n!) \\ \implies \frac{1}{\ln(n^n)} \leq \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$$ Now consider $$\int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{\ln(x^x)}dx = \int_{2}^\infty \frac{1}{x\ln(x)}dx$$

Comment: I haven't started studying integrals... Still Calculus 1

Comment: @Meitar Hmm.. I'll try to think of a different hint. I can't think right now of another easy way to prove this one. Which convergence tests do you know so far?

Comment: @Meitar See *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin, Theorem 3.29, for a proof that $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ diverges without comparing it to an integral.

Comment: The divergence of the $1/n\log n$ series can be seen with Cauchy's condensation test (which can be proven with elementary tools).